# function in console.log prints undefined - JavaScript code. Was expecting to print on console what function returns

Tags: javascript

I am creating function which finds value of key inside JS object. When I run this function I was expecting "data not found" in console log but what I get on console is undefined. Although when inside function instead of return I add console.log there and try printing what I am trying to return it just print it in console.

```
const data = {
    level1: {
      level2: {
        level3: 'some data'
      }
    }
}



function finData(object,key){
    for (const item in object) {
        if(item===key){
            return object[item]
        }else{
            if(typeof object[item] === 'object'){
                finData(object[item],key)
            }else{
                return "data not found"
            }
        }  
    }
}



console.log(finData(data,'level4'))
```

Comment: Common mistake: when making the recursive call, you don't check what it returns, and don't do anything with it.

Comment: @trincot more specifically, the result of the recursive call is not returned

Comment: @VLAZ, they need to check the value before deciding to return it or continue the loop.

Comment: Thanks I found the answer, when calling it recursively just need to add return keyword like return finData(object[item],key)